# Foreach button in my panel containing other panels

Tags: c#

I'm using a custom Button which contains other elements and color styles like TopColor and BotColor. I need to handle this Button inside a panel with other panels.

I'm trying this:

```
foreach(CustomButton btn in panel1.Controls)
{  
    if(btn is CustomButton)
    {
        btn.TopColor=Color.Red;
    }
```

Inside panel1 I'm containing other panels too. And the error I'm getting is
it can't be conversion element panel in a button.

One solution is to separate buttons in one panel. But I want to ask if there is some way to avoid other elements. The reason I don't want to use foreach (Control a in this.Controls) is it doesn't recognise my custom color style TopColor and BotColor

[Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StSOm.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all your controls (as Controls), check if it's a button, then cast it before you try and set the colour.

```
foreach(Control c in panel1.Controls)
{
    if (c is CustomButton)
    {
        (c as CustomButton).TopColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simpler `if(c is CustomButton customButton) { customButton.TopColor = Color.Red; }`

Comment: I wasn't sure which version of C# they were using so went for the long winded version. But yes.

Comment: Thank you very much your solution looks very easy!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an error is that you're trying to cast all your controls to CustomButton, even the panels. You already know the type that you're looking for, so you don't have to loop through every control in your panel.

Assuming all your custom buttons are in panel1 and that you don't need to recurse, you should rather filter the items down to the type that you want and then work with them:

```
var customButtons = panel1.Controls.OfType<CustomButton>();

foreach (CustomButton customButton in customButtons)
 {
     //do what you need here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solution works for you.

```
   private void SetStylesToCustomButtons(Control.ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            if (control is CustomButton)
            {
                (control as CustomButton).TopColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (control is Panel)
            {
                SetStylesToCustomButtons((control as Panel).Controls);
            }
        }
    }
```